# Warning: Error: dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_autoreleasePoolPush

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, grunt-contrib-imagemin

I'm getting an error when imagemin is run on png : Warning: Error: dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_autoreleasePoolPush

i'm on a macbook pro 10.6.8
I installed grunt today along with the plugin's

Any help would be wonderful as google is pointing me to IOS development issues.

Answer (score 0):

The binary is compiled for a newer version of the OS (you're now 4 major releases behind — upgrade if you can!)

Comment: Upgrading is not an option for me. I guess I will have to find a different solution. Thanks!