# Cause of "dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found:" error from ZMQ build?

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, zeromq, npm-install

I'm working on a Meteor app locally on OSX 10.9.5.

I'm getting this error:

```
 dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _node_module_register
```

I believe it has something to do with the zmq package.  More on from the error:

```
Referenced from: /Users/user/node_modules/zmq/build/Release/zmq.node
```

I've tried:

- npm rebuild
- uninstalling zmq & re-installing
- uninstalling, re-installing, then npm rebuild
- deleting node_modules directory, then re-installing zmq to rule out any possible package conflicts.
  (referenced here:  [dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _node_module_register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130692/dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not-found-node-module-register))

Possible problems I'd rather not test unless absolutely necessary (as it requires full upgrade.  I'm on an older computer.):

[Warning: Error: dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_autoreleasePoolPush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642685/warning-error-dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not-found-objc-autore)

[Git > dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _iconv_open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678546/git-dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not-found-iconv-open)

A zmq compiled under a newer version of OSX?  (I'm using 10.9.5.  Upgrading isn't a viable option unless absolutely necessary.)

If this is the problem....

[Handling "dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found" error when nm does not find symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541706/handling-dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not-found-error-when-nm-does)

...How would I statically link the library to zmq???

The full error:

```
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
W20151202-10:02:42.764(2)? (STDERR) dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _node_module_register
W20151202-10:02:42.766(2)? (STDERR)   Referenced from: /Users/user/node_modules/zmq/build/Release/zmq.node
W20151202-10:02:42.766(2)? (STDERR)   Expected in: dynamic lookup
W20151202-10:02:42.766(2)? (STDERR) 
W20151202-10:02:42.767(2)? (STDERR) dyld: Symbol not found: _node_module_register
W20151202-10:02:42.767(2)? (STDERR)   Referenced from: /Users/user/node_modules/zmq/build/Release/zmq.node
W20151202-10:02:42.767(2)? (STDERR)   Expected in: dynamic lookup
W20151202-10:02:42.767(2)? (STDERR) 
=> Exited from signal: SIGTRAP
```

I've been trying to solve this for over a day now.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that you have multiple versions of Node installed and running the install as root and the app as a normal user (or vice versa)?

Comment: I tested running the app with sudo meteor. Which I believe should run it as the root.  I'm still getting the same error.  How would I check the reverse?  I believe meteor loads nodjs??  So meteor would load nodjs as the root with sudo meteor to start the app???

Comment: You need to make sure that the `zmq` module is built using the Node.js that is provided by Meteor (which I believe is shipped with Meteor, it doesn't use a separately installed Node.js). I also don't know about how well Node packages integrate with Meteor nowadays (it used to be pretty difficult, although I never used Meteor myself so I might be lying...). Alternatively, since Meteor is using Node v0.10.40, it may work if you installed that particular version of Node to try and build `zmq`.

Comment: To test this, I went ahead and uninstalled nodjs & meteor completely.  I re-installed both.  Then started with a clean app.  Before doing anything else, I used npm install zmq.  I then added the problematic code "var zeromq = Npm.require('zmq');" to be executed on startup.  I'm getting the exact same error as before.

Comment: Would this test rule out that zmq build and the meteor build are the same?

Comment: Within the Meteor distribution there are `node` and `npm` executables. Try using those (particularly `npm`) to install `zmq`, instead of a separate Node installation.

Comment: From a freshly created Meteor app, within the application directory I enter 'npm install zmq'.  I'm assuming that is using the nodejs within the app directory?  If so, it's still giving me the same error.  Any other ideas?

Comment: No, that wouldn't necessarily use Meteor's node/npm. What does `which npm` return while you're in such a directory?

Comment: It returns, /usr/local/bin/npm.  How would I constrain npm install zmq to us the local app version to install? (Sorry for the newbie question here.)

Comment: I downloaded the latest Meteor installer, and added some instructions for you to try [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/3d89076ef298dcdc2e1a).

Comment: OMG it worked!!!!!! Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix this by removing the node_modules folder and then run

```
$ meteor npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of this error is that there is a mismatch between node versions used to install/run node.js code.

I had this issue because I npm installed with node 5, but my run config was node 0.11.something.

I switched my run config to use node 5, and the problem went away.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well. Had to switch from Node v10 to Node v12 and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

(recap of the comments, for others that are interested; since I don't have any hands-on Meteor experience, my solution may be wrong, in which case, feel free to correct me :)

Meteor comes with its own set of `node` and `npm` executables. If you want to use Node modules that depend on [addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), like `zmq`, you need to make sure that these modules are installed with the Meteor-supplied executables; otherwise, you may run into issues (although it may work if you install the same version of Node that Meteor uses, which seem to be `node@0.10.40` and `npm@1.4.28`, although I don't know if the Meteor executables are "plain" Node/npm or if they are patched).

The executables can be found within the `.meteor` directory. In case of OS X, they are located in `~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.1.10/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/` (although the version number may vary, I suppose).

An easy way for making sure that the Meteor executables are used instead of a globally installed Node/npm, you can add that directory to the start of your `$PATH`:

```
$ export PATH=~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.1.10/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/:$PATH
```

After that, in the same shell session, both `node` and `npm` should now point to the Meteor-supplied versions and you can install addons using them:

```
$ npm install zmq
```